# Undefined notice on unset field

Tags: plugin-development

Still trying to figure my way around Wordpress plugin development, how can I resolve this undefined error? This appears when I add a new post, it can't find the post so I'm trying to figure out how to resolve it with an isset.

`Notice: Undefined index: kk_youtube in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/video_widget/video_widget.php on line 33`

The error is on this line 33:

```
$youtube_link = esc_attr($value['kk_youtube'][0]);
```

I've been trying to wrap it in `isset($post)` but it's still not working.

This is the entire function call.

```
function kk_youtube_handler($post) {
    $value = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $youtube_link = esc_attr($value['kk_youtube'][0]);

    echo '<label for="kk_youtube">YouTube Video Link</label>
          <input type="text" id="kk_youtube" name="kk_youtube" value="' . 
          $youtube_link . '" />';
}
```

Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you're trying to read `$value['kk_youtube']` when there is no `kk_youtube` key in the array (undefined index). Rather than use `isset`, use [`get_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) with the third argument "single" true:

```
$youtube_link = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'kk_youtube', true ) );
```

This is effectively the same as doing:

```
$value = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
if ( isset( $value['kk_youtube'][0] ) )
     $youtube_link = esc_attr( $value['kk_youtube'][0] );
else
     $youtube_link = '';
```

Comment: Ah, thank you sir... I was using the wrong parameter for isset. Thanks for explaining and providing an alternative solution.